# Angular AOT failing at compilation (something with angular/compiler-cli)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot, angular-compiler-cli

After going through the AOT tutorial on the Docs page, I am trying to compile angular 2 AOT and am getting the following error

```
"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json

TypeError: compiler.AnimationParser is not a constructor
at Function.CodeGenerator.create (C:\Projects\NeilKellyClient4\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:108:400)
at codegen (C:\Projects\NeilKellyClient4\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:7:36)
at Object.main (C:\Projects\NeilKellyClient4\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:37:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\NeilKellyClient4\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:16:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
Compilation failed
```

I am getting stuck at this point. Any reason why angular/compiler-cli is throwing this error ?

Comment: I saw someone who had a similar error and downgraded their compiler-cli from 2.2.1 -> 2.1.0. I did the same thing but now I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, it appears to be a version conflict. I had the same issue, and had to reinstall the package to get it to work, with the version specified. I would suggest installing the release versions and re-running until you get what you wanted. For what it's worth, I had same error, and 2.1.2 worked for me.

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli@2.1.2 --save-dev
```

As to *why*, I would speculate the package versions are out of sync. Try running `npm list --depth=0` and see if anything pops up. Might give a hint as to what's out of whack.

Comment: Yeah I ended up trying it again with angular 2.2.0 and compiler-cli 2.2.0 (like the quickstart is as of today.) and it worked. Something was off with versions I don't know what though

Comment: Thank you! I got 5 years older trying to solve this. Upgraded my app to 2.2.0 (angular + compiler), discovered an angular2 bug, downgraded angular but kept the compiler at 2.2.0.. and forgot about it... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way I got rid of it was using 2.2.0 for all the angular packages including compiler-cli. Then did `npm install` again to reload all package dependencies as per 2.2.0 and it worked. Here is a part of package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",
```