# Angular AOT Compiler - TypeError: this.compiler.analyzeModulesAsync is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli, angular-compiler

I'm trying to follow the ahead of time (AOT) compiler instructions here:

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

The project I'm working on has been developed using the quickstart seed, as described here:

https://angular.io/guide/setup

The project has been working fine **without** using the AOT compiler, but when I try to follow the instructions to get the AOT compiler working, I get the following error (this is on Windows 8):

```
C:\Users\zzzzz\Desktop\quickstart>"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p ./src
TypeError: this.compiler.analyzeModulesAsync is not a function
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (C:\Users\zzzzz\Desktop\quickstart\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:32:14)
    at codegen (C:\Users\zzzzz\Desktop\quickstart\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:13:81)
    at Object.main (C:\Users\zzzzz\Desktop\quickstart\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:98:16)
    at main (C:\Users\zzzzz\Desktop\quickstart\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:19:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zzzzz\Desktop\quickstart\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:35:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
Compilation failed
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "~1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "~2.2.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

When I check what version of @angular/compiler I have installed, I get 4.2.2, which appears to be the most current version:

```
C:\Users\zzzzz\Desktop\quickstart>npm view @angular/compiler version
4.2.2
```

Viewing source on Github, I see that there is a function called **analyzeModulesAsync** in angular/packages/compiler/src/aot/compiler.ts:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/aot/compiler.ts

However, when I do a grep on my node_modules folder for **analyzeModulesAsync**, I only see *calls* to that function. I don't see a definition for it. In fact, the class definition in the compiler.d.ts appears to have several differences from the compiler.ts file on Github.

I've tried "reinstalling" by deleting the entire node_modules folder and re-running npm install, and the error message is the same.

I do see a somewhat similar question here: [Angular AOT failing at compilation (something with angular/compiler-cli)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599035/angular-aot-failing-at-compilation-something-with-angular-compiler-cli), but I don't know enough about npm versioning to know what could be out of whack, or how to fix it.

Any ideas on whether I botched some instructions somewhere, or there is something deeper at work?

***SOLUTION***

The problem was with the mismatched versions of @angular/compiler-cli and @angular/platform-server in package.json. Once I changed those to "~4.0.0" to match the rest of the angular modules, deleted the node_modules folder and re-ran `npm install`, the compiler worked.

My working theory is that, because I cloned the quickstart two weeks ago, and ran this command: `npm install @angular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-server --save` from the tutorial yesterday, that's what lead to the version mismatch.

Comment: Why do you use different version `compiler("~4.0.0")` and `compiler-cl("^4.2.2")i`?

Comment: That *may* have happened when I tried to fix issues I got with running this command from the tutorial: npm install @angular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-server --save. Regardless, I made all the versions consistent in my package.json, deleted node_modules, re-ran npm install, and now it appears that the compiler worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rolandus : You smashed it, I had cloned the quickstart a while ago, then added aot packages today which were set to latest. Matching the version numbers to 4.0.0 worked but only once I used the tilde **~** rather than caret *^*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the mismatched versions of @angular/compiler-cli and other angular packages. So we suggest you to i**nstall @angular/compiler-cli package in the same version of other angular packages** in your application.